# AttributeError: 'create_frame' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am relatively new to Python and trying to write a piece of code using tkinter, however I am getting an error. Can soemone help me understand what am I doing wrong here:

```
from tkinter import *
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self,root,geo,name):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry(geo)
        self.root.title(name)

class create_frame:
    def __init__(self,root,name,title,x_pos,y_pos,height,width,bg_col,fg_col,f_size,bold):
        if bold=="Yes":
            name=LabelFrame(root,text=title,font=("verdana",11,"bold"),bg=bg_col,fg=fg_col)
        else:
            name=LabelFrame(root,text=title,font=("verdana",11))            
        name.place(x=x_pos,y=y_pos,relwidth=height,relheight=1)

class create_button:
    def __init__(self,place,Btname,text,row,col,color,font):
        Btname=Button(place,text=text,width=10,bd=2,font=font).grid(row=row,corlumn=col)

root= Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
mainframe=MyApp(root,"1920x1080+0+0","Analaysis App")
ActionsFrame=create_frame(root,"Actions","Actions",0,0,0.2,1,"#001a4d","white",11,"Yes")
BT_DownLoad_EOD_Data=create_button(ActionsFrame,"Download_EOD_Data","Download EOD Data",0,0,"red","verdana 11")

#Btname=Button(ActionsFrame,btnametext="EOD",width=10,bd=2,font="verdana 11").grid(row=0,corlumn=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sidwived.AD-ONE/Desktop/AI BOT/Development/Tkinter/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    BT_DownLoad_EOD_Data=create_button(ActionsFrame,"Download_EOD_Data","Download EOD Data",0,0,"red","verdana 11")
  File "c:/Users/sidwived.AD-ONE/Desktop/AI BOT/Development/Tkinter/main.py", line 18, in __init__
    Btname=Button(place,text=text,width=10,bd=2,font=font).grid(row=row,corlumn=col)
  File "C:\Users\sidwived.AD-ONE\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\sidwived.AD-ONE\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2292, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\sidwived.AD-ONE\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2262, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'create_frame' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Can someone please help me understand what wrong I am doing. I know it is going to be silly but cant find it

Thanks in advance

Siddhartha

Comment: `ActionsFrame` cannot be a `place` that you put the new `Button` into, because it is an instance of your own unrelated class, and not an instance of the `tk.Frame` class. (It's unclear what you think classes are *for*, or why you have defined `create_frame` and `create_button` as classes.)

Comment: instance of `create_frame` not widget, but your class, cannot be master widget of your new widget. I think the same for `create_button` will be problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the class `create_frame` is missing an initializer:

```
self.name = name 

self.title = title
```

because without this python doesn't recognize an instance of your class like Tk here.

Hope I could help